# How to write Hover property with CSS for a piece wih :after and :before properties?

Tags: html, css

I have an hexagon made using after and before properties with css, Now I'm trying to create a glow around the hexagon while hovering, works perfect for the center of the piece but not for the points of the hexagon (top and bottom pieces) with :after and :before.

```css
.hexagon1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  width: 106px; 
  height: 61.20px;
  background-color: #02cd68;
  margin: 30.60px 0;
  top:44px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.hexagon1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #02cd68;
}

.hexagon1:before,
.hexagon1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 53px solid transparent;
  border-right: 53px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 30.60px solid #02cd68;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.hexagon1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 30.60px solid #02cd68;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon1"></div>
```

I've tried with .hexagon1:after:hover but there's no result:( any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: If you're not too terribly concerned with browser support ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)), you can switch your `box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #02cd68;` on `.hexagon1:hover` to `filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px #02cd68);`. Bleeding-edge CSS is powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `after`, `before`, and `hover` like the following code:

```
.hexagon1:hover:before {
//...
}

.hexagon1:hover:after {
//...
}
```

But your question is a bit different. I have searched on internet but I couldn't find any proper solution. Here is my solution:

- Create two hexagons (One should be bigger than another to be seen as shadow)
- Order them by using `z-index`
- Don't show the hexagon, which is at the back until the front is on hover

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/7nn5v06z/

Comment: wow pal! clever way to solve it! you're right! that's a good way to do it! thanks!!! @kaanBurakSener